# Escaping backtick in a variable string

Tags: powershell

Pretty simple question, I don't see it listed yet.

```
$a = "`4Test `!User"
$a | Out-File test.txt
```

Output I want:

```
`4Test `!User"
```

Output I get:

```
4Test !User
```

Comment: Use a non expandable string instead, `'`4Test `!User'` (single quotes)

Comment: If you do need an expandable string, just double the backtick (backtick-escaping the backtick so to speak).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$a = '`4Test `!User'
$a
```

Output:

```
`4Test `!User
```

Explanation:

> A string enclosed in **double quotation** marks is an expandable string. Variable names preceded by a dollar sign ($) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing. for example:

```
$i = 5
"The value of $i is $i."
```

Output:

```
The value of 5 is 5.
```

> A string enclosed in **single quotation** marks is a verbatim string. The
> string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No
> substitution is performed. for example:

```
$i = 5
'The value of $i is $i.'
```

Output:

```
The value $i is $i.
```

for further information see: [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)